# wordpress/woocomerce page description is breaking my script some how

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, pdf, iframe

I am working on a script to simply display an iframe or a pdf depending on if a domain is blocked on the users network. So far the code seems to work when tested on something like `http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_doc_write5`
but when placed inside of the wordpress description field or the woocommerce short description field, it just does not work and I can't figure out as to why. Please help.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$.ajax({
    url: "//e.issuu.com/embed.html#8480834/9035419",
    type: "HEAD",
    error:
        function(){
document.getElementById("viewer").innerHTML = "<iframe src=\"http://www.analysis.im/uploads/seminar/pdf-sample.pdf\" type=\"application/x-pdf\" width=\"500\" height=\"400\"></iframe></br>";
        },
    success:
    function(){
document.getElementById("viewer").innerHTML = "<div id=\"book\" class=\"issuuembed\" style=\"width: 650px; height: 464px;\" data-configid=\"8480834/4280408\"></div><script src=\"//e.issuu.com/embed.js\" async=\"true\"></script>";
}

});

//--></script>

<div id="viewer">testing</div>
```

Comment: Did you uncomment the <script> tag? It's commented in the example you gave above.

Comment: exactly as it is tested outside of wordpress works. and i just moved it to another line, no change @agentb26

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress strips down the html which is why my code wasn't working, I found plugins that fixed the issue